# Disable Gradle Cache for a specific Dependency

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have a specific dependency which is very transitive, heavy use of SNAPSHOTS in development.  I would like to always pull the latest version of this dependency, but no others.

Is there a way to specify this specific dependency not be cached?

Comment: I am not sure if can be a solution.Take a look here:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_get_gradle_to_download_newer_snapshots_to_gradle_cache_when_using_an_ivy_repository

about changing attribute.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I think that may actually solve my problem, testing now.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the TTL for snapshot dependencies (24h by default), but you cannot do this for a specific dependency.